# Using Functions In Python

Tags: python, function, readfile

i needed to create a program that would read a text file and count the number of lines, words and characters. I got it all working below if seperated individually but i wanted to convert it into using functions so it can read the file once, but i keep getting different answers and unsure what im doing wrong.

*Words Code*

```
print ' '
fname = "question2.txt"
infile = open ( fname, 'r' )
fcontents = infile.read()

words = fcontents.split()
cwords = len(words)

print "Words: ",cwords
```

*Characters Code*

```
fname = "question2.txt"
infile = open ( fname, 'r' )
fcontents = infile.read()

char = len(fcontents)

print "Characters: ", char
```

*Lines Code*

```
fname = "question2.txt"
infile = open ( fname, 'r' )
fcontents = infile.readlines()

lines = len(fcontents)

print "Lines: ", lines
```

*Correct Results*

> Words:  87
>   Characters:  559
>   Lines:  12

This is what I came up while trying to use functions but just cant figure out what's wrong.

```
def filereader():
    fname = 'question2.txt'
    infile = open ( fname, 'r' )
    fcontents = infile.read()
    fcontents2 = infile.readlines()

    return fname, infile, fcontents, fcontents2


def wordcount(fcontents):
    words = fcontents.split(fcontents)
    cwords = len(words)
    return cwords

def charcount(fcontents):
    char = len(fcontents)
    return char

def linecount(fcontents2):
    lines = len(fcontents2)
    return lines


def main():

    print "Words: ", wordcount ('cwords')
    print "Character: ", charcount ('char')
    print "Lines: ", linecount ('lines')

main()
```

*Wrong Results*

> Words:  2
>   Character:  4
>   Lines:  5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `filereader` in `main`:

```
def main():
    fname, infile, fcontents, fcontents2 = filereader()
    print "Words: ", wordcount (fcontents)
    print "Character: ", charcount (fcontents)
    print "Lines: ", linecount (fcontents2)
```

Otherwise, how would you obtain the values for `fcontents` and `fcontents2` to pass to your other functions? You also need to fix `filereader` to make sure it will read the file once:

```
def filereader():
    fname = 'question2.txt'
    infile = open ( fname, 'r' )
    fcontents = infile.read()
    fcontents2 = fcontents.splitlines(True)
    return fname, infile, fcontents, fcontents2
```

Note that the line for `fcontents2` has been modified to split `fcontents` on newlines (see [`str.splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)). This will also gives you a list of strings as `.readlines()` would do.

Answer (score 2):

```
    infile = open ( fname, 'r' )
    fcontents = infile.read()
    fcontents2 = infile.readlines()
```

You cannot read from a file twice.

Comment: You could also reposition the cursor with `seek()`, could you not?

Comment: @sr2222 - yes, but you have to do it. Otherwise it is better to read the file once and then split it according to needs.

Comment: You might want to suggest `fcontents2 = fcontents.splitlines()` or something to that effect.

Comment: @eumiro Granted.  Just pointing out that 'cannot' is not, strictly speaking, true.

Answer (score 0):

When you read from a file, the file handle remembers its position in the file. Thus, after your call `infile.read()`, `infile` will be placed at the end of the file. When you then call `infile.readlines()`, it will try to read all the characters between its current position and the end of the file, and hence return an empty list.

You can rewind the file to its initial position using `infile.seek(0)`. Thus:

```
>>> fcontents = infile.read()
>>> infile.seek(0)
>>> flines = infile.readlines()
```

will work.

Alternatively, having read the file into the string `fcontents`, you can split the string into lines using `splitlines`:

```
>>> fcontents = infile.read()
>>> flines = fcontents.splitlines()
```